# theano.scan output gradient is different if calculation is done inside or outside scan

Tags: python, theano

So I have the following code

```
def step(i, rng, prev, A, B):
    a = A*prev
    b = B*a
    return b, a, a+rng

rng = RandomStreams(lasagne.random.get_rng().randint(1,2147462579))

A = T.scalar("A")
B = T.scalar("B")

outputs, _ = theano.scan(step, 
                         sequences=[T.arange(1,5),rng.normal([4])], 
                         outputs_info=[T.ones_like(A),None, None], 
                         non_sequences=[A,B])
res, re, samp = outputs
grad = T.grad(cost=re.sum(), wrt=A)
func = theano.function([A,B],[grad])

print func(3.0,2.0)
```

The code above gives and output of [array(985.0)], which is correct. 
However, if I do the following gradient instead

```
grad = T.grad(cost=(re-samp).sum(), wrt=A, consider_constant=[samp])
```

the gradient comes out 0. 
More interesting, if I do the `a+rng` step after outside of scan, i.e., using the `re` value to generate `samp`, the gradient comes out [array(985.0)] correctly again (when using `consider_constant=[samp]`, which is what I'm interested in).

Any hint to why this is the case? I absolutely need to perform the random computation inside the scan, 
so it would be nice to know if there's way to get the gradient working correctly in this circumstance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`theano.gradient.disconnected_grad`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/gradient.html#theano.gradient.disconnected_grad)

```
from theano import gradient

def step(i, rng, prev, A, B):
    a = A*prev
    b = B*a
    return b, a, a+rng

rng = RandomStreams(lasagne.random.get_rng().randint(1,2147462579))

A = T.scalar("A")
B = T.scalar("B")

outputs, _ = theano.scan(step,
                         sequences=[T.arange(1,5),rng.normal([4])],
                         outputs_info=[T.ones_like(A),None, None],
                         non_sequences=[A,B])
res, re, samp = outputs
grad = T.grad(cost=(re-gradient.disconnected_grad(samp)).sum(), wrt=A)
func = theano.function([A,B],[grad])

print func(3.0,2.0)
```

Outputs

```
[array(985.0, dtype=float32)]
```